# Why am I seeing error configure: error: No package 'gtk+-3.0' found when I installed libgtk-3-dev?

Tags: apt, gtk, emacs

I have successfully installed `libgtk-3-dev` using `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`. However, when I run `./configure` to install emacs, I get an error showing the following:

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

I am wondering what I am missing or what the error is telling me. Could anyone please help.

I have already installed all the build essentials and checked them already.

Running on **Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS**

Answer (score 3):

okay. Figured it out with some googling. Needed to set the the environmental variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as follows:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```